# How do i combine two git commits into a single commit without using an interactive git rebasing?

Tags: git, github, rebase

I am working on a feature branch that is used by other team as well and they have a lot of developers so there is a lot of commits happening from their end.
I last committed some 10 days ago and  again i am planning to commit today but i want to ensure a single commit from my end.

I know i can achieve this using "git rebase -i HEAD~n" but i dont know what number to put in place of n as in these 10 days there have more than 20+ commits from other team's end.This command is a good option if you have consecutive commits but it is not ideal for my scenario.

Though i have the hashcodes of the git commits done from my end,so is there any way apart from git interactive rebasing where i could just use one of my git hashcode as "pick" and the other one as "squash".
It will save me the trouble of going through some 20+ git commits.

Comment: You can squash when you merge

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble  Can you elaborate please, i didnt get that,which merge you are referring to?

Comment: Don't. Since there are 10 days of commits following, your opportunity to merge the commits without causing havoc are over. Unless you revert the old commit, then commit the combined changes, but that makes little sense if you ask me. What are you trying to accomplish my merging these commits into 1?

Comment: When the feature branch merges, you can choose to do it as a squash-merge, which creates a single commit out of everything—this way, you dont have to rebase-squash everything.

Comment: @jessehouwing I just want want a clean history from my end since the new commit contain changes that are mostly on of my last commit,very few new features have been added that are new from the last commit.But offcourse this thing is not followed by the other team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* possible to achieve your desired result without using `git rebase -i`.  It's worth working through the method so that you really *understand* what `git rebase` does, whether or not you use the `-i` option.

**It is *probably unwise* to achieve your desired result at all**, though only you and your co-workers can really determine this.

One way you would do this manually is to `git checkout` a specific commit by hash ID, and create a new branch name pointing to this commit.  The commit you choose here should be the one *just before* the two commits in question.

Then you would `git cherry-pick -n` the two commits that you wanted to squash into one new commit, and use `git commit` to commit the result.

Now you're faced with the problem of additionally using `git cherry-pick` to copy each *subsequent* commit onto the new branch.  That's not all that difficult—in fact, it should all go automatically, given the right hash IDs.  You just have to find the right hash IDs.

Once you're done, you need to convince your co-workers to abandon the existing feature branch and use your new, rebuilt feature branch.  This new branch has copies of the original commits, but they are new-and-improved in that they are built upon your squashed replacement of your original two commits.

If that sounds a bit convoluted, well, it's the same as what your `git rebase -i` would have done—except that when you do it with `git rebase -i`, you have to convince your co-workers to abandon a branch named `feature/foo` in favor of a new branch whose name is *still `feature/foo`*, which is kind of confusing!

---

To do this with `git rebase -i` without having to *count* commits (as in `HEAD~20`), use:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph
```

to get a good look at the commits you intend to rebase.  You'll get a one-line listing of the commits with abbreviated hash IDs and their commit subjects, plus an ASCII drawing of the commit graph.  Make sure it has no branch-and-merge patterns in the commits you'll copy (or that if it does, it's OK if you throw away all the merges)—in this case, that means that it's just a series of `*` markings before the commits you intend to copy-and-replace.  Then, instead of *counting*, use:

```
git rebase -i <hash>
```

where the *`hash`* is the one from the first commit you *won't* copy-or-modify.

Note that the end result of a rebase like this is a *new series of commits*, even if you use the *old* branch name to identify it.  That's why it's usually a bad idea: it is not just *your* commits that you'll discard-and-replace, but other commits that other people are using, and still making right now.  So *they* have to switch over to these new copies that you made of *their* commits too.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer covers most approaches.Convincing the other team to go with a new branch as suggested by you in part 1 doesnt look easy as they have a demo a day after.As far as i understand,It is more wise to leave these 2 commits instead of  squashing them into one as per my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation (feature branch with lots of other people's changes), what I do is always keep my not pushed commits on "top" of other commits by always doing `git pull --rebase`. This will fetch the branch as is on the server and will put my local commits on top. Note that this will change my local branch history, but not the remote branch history, so on push there will be **no** need to use the `--force` :).

Then when you are ready to send your work to the server using just one commit you can simply squash by finding the hash of the top server commit and:

`git reset --soft HASH_BEFORE_MY_FIRST_LOCAL_COMMIT`

This will leave all changes from your local commits already staged. You just need to commit them by specifying a new message using `git commit -m "..."`, `git gui` or your preferred tool. Note that you won´t have at this moment each individual message so if you need them it is better to get them before you do the git reset.

Down side of this approach: When you use the `git pull --rebase` git will apply each of your local commits one by one. If a conflict occurs, you will have to resolve it and use `git rebase --continue`. The down side is that depending on the number of local commits you can take conflicts several times.